# Why is the operator $M_a |x\rangle= |a \cdot x \pmod{N} \rangle $ unitary?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, unitarity, order-finding

If $N\geq 2$, $a\in \mathbb{Z}_N$, and $a^r= 1$ for some $r$. Consider the operator $M_a$, which is related to order finding :

$M_a |x\rangle= |a \cdot x \pmod{N} \rangle $ if $x\in \mathbb{Z}_N$

What is an easy way to show that it's a unitary?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? have you attempted anything to see why it's a unitary operation?

Comment: I have no idea on what ket 3, for example, can possibly be. Or ket of the equiv. class 3 of $\mathbb{Z}_N$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $\gcd(N,a)=1$, then the operator $M_a$ mapping $x\in\mathbb Z_N$ to $a\cdot x \pmod N$ is a permutation, which means that it’s reversible, ergo unitary.

Comment: +1 The assumption is in fact not only sufficient, but also a necessary condition for unitarity of $M_a$. If $\gcd(N,a)=b>1$, then $N=ub$ and $a=vb$ for some non-zero $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}_N$ and $M_a|u\rangle=|0\rangle=M_a|0\rangle$, so $M_a$ fails to be injective.

Comment: @AdamZalcman indeed, as another way to state the same, in the OP's framing $a$ must generate all of $\mathbb Z_N$, and hence $r$ must equal $N$.